# Confusion regarding a participle phrase (probably)

Tags: punctuation, present-participles

So, I was scrolling through my facebook news feed when I came across a status someone had put up that read "I get road rage walking behind people." .

Now, the "walking behind people" part modifies the "I" if i'm not wrong.
So, wouldn't there be a comma following the word rage?

Comment: Care to elaborate on what you mean by **wouldn't**?

Comment: @TRomano - I think the poster just means "Shouldn't there be a comma...?"

Comment: @stangdon: Wouldn't the Facebook copy editors have prevented such an error?

Comment: I think it is absurd to be discussing punctuation on a Facebook news feed.

Comment: In my opinion the original sentence is fine without a comma. (Facebook copy editors? I can't tell if @TRomano is joking.)

Answer (score -2):

That post technically contains a **misplaced modifier** so punctuation is not really relevant. In that sentence, **walking behind people** functions as an adjective and modifies **I**.  Therefore, it should be placed closer to **I** to clarify that it modifies **I**.

As written, **walking behind people** technically is describing **rage**. Note that it does not make sense to describe **rage** as **walking** so English speakers will assume **walking behind people** modifies **I** and not misunderstand the meaning.  However, consider the following sentence:

> I saw a girl walking down the street.

In this sentence, both **girl** and **I** can potentially be **walking** so you have to rely on grammar rather than the meaning of the words to figure out who is walking.  **Girl** is being modified because is it closer to **walking down the street**.

If you wanted to clarify that **I** was **walking**, you have to invert the word order:

> Walking down the street, I saw a girl.

So in proper English, the post above should be written:

> Walking behind people, I get road rage.

Now just as a final note, the sentence I wrote above is completely correct and the one in the post is not.  However, the correct sentence differs from the incorrect one in that it emphasizes **walking behind people**. The incorrect one is more of a simple statement with **walking behind people** thrown in as an afterthought.

Comment: In my opinion the original sentence has a vibe that complements the writer's meaning.

Comment: You guys are brutal.  Is something in this answer not correct?

Comment: Well I didn't down-vote, but I don't agree with your conclusion. In my opinion the original sentence  emphasises that the (metaphorical) road rage happens while walking behind people - I don't think that comes across as an afterthought.